# Sort just one member of the classes in a vector, leaving the other members unchanged

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

There are tons of answers for sorting a vector of struct in regards to a member variable. That is easy with `std::sort` and a predicate function, comparing the structs member. Really easy.

*But I have a **different** question*. Assume that I have the following struct:

```
struct Test {
    int a{};
    int b{};
    int toSort{};
};
```

and a vector of that struct, like for example:

```
std::vector<Test> tv{ {1,1,9},{2,2,8},{3,3,7},{4,4,6},{5,5,5} };
```

I do not want to sort the vectors elements, but only the values in the member variable. So the expected output should be equal to:

```
std::vector<Test> tvSorted{ {1,1,5},{2,2,6},{3,3,7},{4,4,8},{5,5,9} };
```

I wanted to have the solution to be somehow a generic solution. Then I came up with a (sorry for that) preprocessor-macro-solution. Please see the following example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Test {
    int a{};
    int b{};
    int toSort{};
};

#define SortSpecial(vec,Struct,Member) \
do { \
    std::vector<decltype(Struct::Member)> vt{}; \
    std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(vt), [](const Struct& s) {return s.Member; }); \
    std::sort(vt.begin(), vt.end()); \
    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&vt, i = 0U](Struct & s) mutable {s.Member = vt[i++]; }); \
} while (false)

int main()
{
    // Define a vector of struct Test
    std::vector<Test> tv{ {1,1,9},{2,2,8},{3,3,7},{4,4,6},{5,5,5} };
    for (const Test& t : tv) std::cout << t.a << " " << t.b << " " << t.toSort << "\n";

    // Call sort macro
    SortSpecial(tv, Test, toSort);

    std::cout << "\n\nSorted\n";
    for (const Test& t : tv) std::cout << t.a << " " << t.b << " " << t.toSort << "\n";
}
```

---

---

Since macros shouldn't be used in C++, here my questions:

**1. Is a solution with the algorithm library possible?**

**2. Or can this be achieved via templates?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To translate your current solution to a template solution is fairly straight forward.

```
template <typename T, typename ValueType>
void SpecialSort(std::vector<T>& vec, ValueType T::* mPtr) {
    std::vector<ValueType> vt;
    std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(vt), [&](const T& s) {return s.*mPtr; });
    std::sort(vt.begin(), vt.end());
    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&, i = 0U](T& s) mutable {s.*mPtr = vt[i++]; });
}
```

And we can call it by passing in the vector and a pointer-to-member.

```
SpecialSort(tv, &Test::toSort);
```

Comment: Very good solution. And indeed straight forward. Thanks. +1 + accept

Answer (score 1):

Somewhow like this (You just need to duplicate, rename and edit the "switchToShort" funtion for the rest of the variables if you want):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Test {
    int a{};
    int b{};
    int toSort{};
};
void switchToShort(Test &a, Test &b) {
    if (a.toSort > b.toSort) {
        int temp = a.toSort;
        a.toSort = b.toSort;
        b.toSort = temp;
    }
}
//void switchToA(Test& a, Test& b) { ... }
//void switchToB(Test& a, Test& b) { ... }
inline void sortMemeberValues(std::vector<Test>& data, void (*funct)(Test&, Test&)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < data.size(); j++) {
            (*funct)(data[i], data[j]);
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    std::vector<Test> tv { { 1, 1, 9 }, { 2, 2, 8 }, { 3,3 ,7 }, { 4, 4, 6 }, { 5, 5, 5} };
        sortMemeberValues(tv, switchToShort);
        //sortMemeberValues(tv, switchToA);
        //sortMemeberValues(tv, switchToB);
    for (const Test& t : tv) std::cout << t.a << " " << t.b << " " << t.toSort << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) (and soon [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) in C++20), you might simply do:

```
auto r = tv | ranges::view::transform(&Test::toSort);
std::sort(r.begin(), r.end());
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65c3ba157fda01c6)

Comment: Also very good answer. This is the version using new C++20 features. Even better than templates, +1. But at the moment I am still using C++17 and only standard libraries.